# Online stock portfolio charts

Tags: charts, finance

There are a lot of sites I can go to and get a chart of any stock such as finance.google.com, finance.yahoo.com, and others.

But I want to get a chart of how a portfolio consisting of multiple stocks would have performed.  For instance, suppose I have a portfolio consisting of 100 shares of MSFT, 50 shares of GOOG, and short 100 shares of T.  I would like to type in "100*MSFT + 50*GOOG - 100*T" in the stock ticker and have it show me the graph, but that doesn't work.  Perhaps one of the existing services does have it and I just haven't figured out how to use it.  For instance, some reading suggests that Google Finance will let me graph my portfolio, but I just don't see where, or if they are even really talking about what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the combination of [python](http://python.org), [ystockquote](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ystockquote) and one of the many python plotting libraries such as [matplotlib pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html), [Plotly](https://plot.ly/) or [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) - the Bokeh site even has an [example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stocks.html) that looks very like what you would like to do.

You would probably be even better with [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which can integrate with several sites as can be seen [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html).

With pandas getting the data is ridiculously easy, *filched from [this](http://dogdogfish.com/python-2/stock-prices-and-python-pandas-to-the-rescue/) dogfish blog*:

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
company_information = pd.read_csv(‘mycompanylist.csv’)
mega_frame = [DataReader(company.strip(), "yahoo", datetime(2015,1,1), datetime.now().date()) for company in company_information[company_information.Sector == ‘Technology’][‘Symbol’]]
symbol_list = [symbol for symbol in company_information[company_information.Sector == ‘Technology’][‘Symbol’]]
```